# system locale are setting improperly on Redhat

Tags: centos, ssh, rhel, sudo, locale

On `Redhat 7.9` (fresh installation) many command returns warning like on example:

```
# yum repolist
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
```

When check locale it returns:

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I've not clue why there is `C.UTF-8` in the system is installed with:

```
# cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Moreover, when I run:

```
# localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I get correct locales in new session via `"su -"` but they are gone when I exit and `"sudo -i"` or `"ssh"` to the host again...

```
# su -
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
# exit
logout
$ sudo -i
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


$ ssh host
[host]$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How to get locales set permanently for what is configured in: `/etc/locale.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: `yum install glibc-langpack-en` fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

the root cause was "wrong" locale set on ssh client side:

> ...`ssh` sessions, by default, accept locale environment variables from the client (where the `ssh` command was ran), this can override what the server may want to set.

Comment: I had this issue when connecting from macOS to a Linux system via SSH. To resolve it I configured correct locale settings in ~/.bashrc. I added `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
dnf install glibc-langpack-en
```

Fixed it for me on AlmaLinux 9.1. Thanks to @Sérgio for the sug!